# Android SwitchPreference OnPreferenceChangeListener event goes wild when scrolling in PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

In my Android app I have a SettingsActivity. In there is a Fragment for a settings page that holds a dynamic list of SwitchPreferences.

```
for (Area a : areas) {
    final SwitchPreference sp = new SwitchPreference(getActivity());
    sp.setTitle(a.getName());
    sp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)   {
              ...
          }
    }
    addPreference(sp);
}
```

That works great on all devices but one: a HTC One Mini 2 with Android 4.4.2.

There when scrolling in the Preference Screen the `onPreferenceChange` event fires all the time for different preferences I haven't even clicked.

Is that a Android bug?

Comment: Quick question - what method is the above code in? onCreate()?

Comment: OnCreate of the Fragment

Comment: Hmm. And it's just the OnPreferenceChangeListener that is called many times? Or is onCreate() repeatedly called too?

Comment: It is the Listener. I debugged it. I scroll and it fires in a not logical order events for random SwitchPreferences.

Comment: That _is_ strange. I don't know why that would be happening. Maybe they implemented it weird on the device. There's a SwitchPreference in the support.v14 library - does that have the same problem?